# Slow loading Category Page Magento 2.4.0

Tags: category, page, magento2.4.0, slow-response, loading

I am **experiencing slow loading Category Pages** using **Magento 2.4.0**. We have **27,000 products** of which approximately **6,000 are for the Magento website**.  The other **21,000+ are for eBay and Amazon**. Normal load time for a Category page with 5,000+ products is less than 2 seconds.  Long load time for the same page can be 10+ seconds.  I have found that I can make the Category Page load normally again if I reindex these six indexes and then clearing any Invalidated Cache files (usually Page Cache will be invalidated after a reindex).

1. Category Products
2. Product Categories
3. Catalog Rule Product
4. Product EAV
5. Catalog Product Rule
6. Product Price

I must check our website for slow loading Category Pages every couple of hours.  I must reindex those 6 Product Indexes 3 or 4 times every day.  I have not been able to find an error in the logs when this happens.  And I have not been able to identify the cause.  Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.
The website is hillcountrycustomcycles.com.  We push a lot of graphics so the first page will take a couple of seconds to load. But after the initial load, the site should load quickly.

Comment: Issue could be poisoned cache, try leave block cache disabled, don't reindex, problem still persists?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I disabled the cache for Blocks HTML output.  I will let you know the result.

Comment: Here 12 days since issuing the command "php bin/magento cache:disable block_html" to disable the BLOCK_HTML cache we have had NO incidents of unusually slow loading Category Pages.  I think that is a good workaround.  Does Magento Development plan to do anything about this malfunction?

Answer (score -1):

Your site load's so fast. I'm near giving up trying to make our site faster

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/201081)